# ask the radius of convergence of power series

Tags: analysis

Baby Rudin 3.39 tells me the given the power series $\Sigma c_n z^n$, put

$$\alpha = \limsup \sqrt[n]{|c_n|}, R=1/\alpha$$

Then R is called the radius of convergence of $\Sigma c_n z^n$. But when I try to do exercise 3.9, the solution just uses $\lim \frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}}$ to find R. Why we can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are various approches to calculate the radius of convergence:

- the one you use is based on the [Root Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_test)
- the one proposed is based on the [Ratio Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_test)

Both are valid and choosing one over the other depends on the given power series.

Comment: I know the ratio test. But I don't learn the ratio test in the power series setting.

Comment: It's basically the same thing: if you put $a_n=c_nz^n$ you know that by the ratio test the series converges if 
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}<1\iff \lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{c_{n+1}\cdot z}{c_n}<1\iff z<\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{c_n}{c_{n+1}}=:R$$